# Problems adding slick.js on a Slate Shopify theme

Tags: shopify, slick.js

I used shopify slate as a base theme to create my store. I have used slick.js on other shopify stores and never had a problem. For some reason I am getting this error on the console.

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).slick is not a function TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function

I first load jQuery, then slick-theme.scss, then slick.min.js and finally I add the slick script on the page I plan to use it.

Thanks

Comment: First check if your `slick.js` is really loading in your DOM, if you have access to to it via the provided URL then it might be something else.

Comment: @drip Yes, slick is indeed being loaded in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer by my own. I was calling jQuery 2 times. One on the theme.liquid and another one on vendor.js.